# AWS and Shibboleth/SAML

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, saml, shibboleth

I have been looking into whether it is possible to use Shibboleth/SAML with Amazon Web Services.

I'm finding very little information on this. As far as I can tell, it is possible to install Shibboleth/SAML on an EC2 server as a Service Provider.

What I am not so sure on is whether it is possible to tie all of AWS to Shibboleth - and how this would work.

My knowledge of all three are vaguely fuzzy - I've been doing a great deal of reading, but I'm not really familiar with this technology at all.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are trying to do is use identity federation to grant a user [temporary security credentials](http://awsdocs.s3.amazonaws.com/STS/latest/sts-ug.pdf) to perform AWS api calls.  You would like your users to authenticate to your own identity provider (Shibboleth in this case), and be granted access to AWS services based on that authentication.

A good example of this that you can use as a framework is in this [AWS sample code](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1288653099190193?_encoding=UTF8&fromSearch=1&queryArg=searchQuery&searchPath=code&searchQuery=token&x=0&y=0).

In a nutshell:

You need a proxy that the users connect to, passing in their authentication credentials.  You would then verify them by authenticating to Shibboleth, AD, LDAP or whatever.

You need a [Token Vending Machine](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/09/updated-mobile-sdks-for-aws-improved-credential-management.html) that your proxy would then call to get a valid AWS secret key using GetFederationTokenRequest.

Your client would then use the token given to it to make the AWS api calls.

[image: AWS image showing temporary credential workflow]

The concepts of federated identity include terms like [STS, SP, and IdP](http://www.empowerid.com/learningcenter/technologies/service-identity-providers), if you are looking for a starting place to research the topic more.